# Fetch data from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi In my application I designed one form with HallTicketNo if i click the submit button it will goto result page based on the hallticket no i want to fetch all the details.My proble is result.php it showing blank page fetching is not working can anyone help me

index.php:

```
 <html>
      <head>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_register.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/responsive.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation_script.js"></script> 
      </head>

      <body>
      <hr>
      <img src="images/banner1.jpg" width="100%" />
      <hr>
      <section id="container">
      <form id="result form" action="result.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
      <div>
        <label class="desc" id="title1" >Hall Ticket No.</label>
        <div>
          <input id="name" name="uname" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1">
        <span class="val_name"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_registration" value="Submit" /><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
        </div>
        </div>  
    </form>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

result.php:

```
 <?php 
    session_start(); 
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">   
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_register.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/responsive.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="images/banner.jpg" width="100%" />
    <section id="container">
    <?php
    include "../db.php";

    $hallticket = $_REQUEST["uname"];   
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM results where Hall_Ticket_No='$hallticket'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);   
    ?>
    <div id="title" align="center"><h3>Exam Results</h3></div>
    <div id="tab">
    <table align="center">

    <tr><td><b>HallTicketNo</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['HallTicketNo'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>RNO</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['RNO'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>FirstName</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['FirstName'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>LastName</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['LastName'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>ClassID</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['ClassID'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>ClassName</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['ClassName'];?>
    <tr><td><b>ExamID</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['ExamID'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>ExamName</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['ExamName'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>ClassResult</b></td><td> : <?php echo $row['ClassResult'];?></td></tr>

    <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div id="sign" align="right"><img src="images/sign.png" height=100 width=80></div>
    <br>
    <center><a href="index.php"><input type="button" value="home" /></a></center>
    </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Than you

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Turn displaying errors on (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21427437/3110982) and check what causes the error. Besides that, you should really read about using PDO, especially read about SQL injections, as your code is vulnerable for that type of attack.

Comment: Have you checked if $_SESSION['id'] is set? use var_dump($_SESSION); as the top of the page after the <?php tag to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In index.php you are not starting session and not registering session id. That is why the if condition of your result.php is not executing.
In index.php do add this line.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']= "1213"; //your id here
?>
```

Comment: hi can you tell me what is the id

Comment: @user3437313 the id you are checking in result.php in session if (isset($_SESSION['id']))

Comment: @user3437313 are you registering "id" in session somewhere.if yes than simply start session in index.php in <?php session_start(); ?> in top of index.php. Your session is broken.

Comment: $hallticket = $_REQUEST["uname"];   
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM results where Hall_Ticket_No='$hallticket'");

Comment: if i use the where condition it showing as a blank details

Comment: without where condition it retrieve the details but same only coming for all the hall ticket no

Comment: @user3437313 and you are not using connection parameter in mysql_query("your query here",$con)

Comment: $hallticket = $_REQUEST["uname"]; $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM results where Hall_Ticket_No='$hallticket'");

Comment: these two lines only i made mistake can you tell me please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51485/discussion-between-dkakoti-and-user3437313)